# adonisjs v4 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

I'm getting this error when using `migration:run`
and my schema is:

```
    'use strict'

    const Schema = use('Schema')

    class UserSchema extends Schema {
        up() {
            this.create('users', table => {
                table.increments()
                table.string('username').notNullable().unique()
                table.string('email').notNullable().unique()
                table.string('password').notNullable()
                table.string('rule').notNullable().defaultTo(0)
                table.string('parent').defaultTo(0)
                table.string('money').notNullable().defaultTo(0)
                table.boolean('type').defaultTo(0)
                table.boolean('state').defaultTo(0)
                table.timestamps()
            })
        }

        down() {
            this.drop('users')
        }
    }

module.exports = UserSchema
```

this error happens only when i add `.unique()` to the schema, if I remove it, it works like a charm.

Please help me solve this. Thanks!

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Try changing encoding of your database/table to for example utf8_general_ci and retry

Comment: i'm using utf8mb4_persian_ci and getting the error yes changing to utf8_general_ci solve's the problem but what is wrong with utf8mb4_persian_ci ?